# Windows Azure - Persistence of OS Settings when using WebRoles

Tags: windows, azure, azure-web-roles

I've been watching some videos from the build conference re: Inside Windows Azure etc.
My take away from one of them was that unless I loaded in a preconfigured VHD into a virtual machine role, I would lose any system settings that I might have made should the instance be brought down or recycled.

So for instance, I have a single account with 2 Web Roles running multiple (small) websites. To make that happen I had to adjust the settings in the Hosts file. I know my websites will be carried over in the event of failure because they are defined in the ServiceConfiguration.csfg but will my hosts file settings also carry over to a fresh instance in the event of a failure?

i.e. how deep/comprehensive is my "template" with a web role?

Comment: Although it's technically feasible to create a Powershell script or a C# program (in the `OnStart()` method of the hosting WebRole.cs) that could recreate the changes, I'm not sure I understand why you need to change the `hosts` file on a server at all - could you clarify? Usually you'd define the DNS entries for a Web site through an external third-party DNS host, most typically the registrar of your domain.

Comment: Hi there. It's possible to use a single IP to host multiple websites. In this case Azure offers a single IP address (u can purchase more) by default. And the sites are small enough that they dont really need or would otherwise be cost ineffective to run under their own web roles. So Ive shifted them to Azure and away from discountasp.net and use the host header file to serve the proper site.

Comment: @nsm - you don't need to change the `hosts` file on the server for that...

Comment: @Jeremy - Thx Im now finding that out. It's weird now every search i run on the topic turns up multiple resources describing how to do it sans hosts file. Theres a great vid here http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Cloud+Cover/Cloud-Cover-Episode-37-Multiple-Websites-in-a-Web-Role about it. I dont know where i got my info from the first time round. I must have stepped off a link about something else into that idea. Has it ALWAYS been the case that you didn;t need a host header file in Azure or is this some reasonably new feature? i.e. <12 months.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `hosts` file will be reconstructed on any full redeployment or reimage.

In general, you should avoid relying on changes to *any* file that is created by the operating system. If your application is migrated to another server it will be running on a new virtual machine with its own new copy of Windows, and so the changes will suddenly appear to have vanished.

The same will happen if you perform a deployment to the Azure "staging" environment and then perform a "swap VIP": the "staging" environment will not have the changes made to the operating system file.

Microsoft intentionally don't publish inner details of what Azure images look like as they will most likely change in future, but currently

- drive C: holds the boot partition, logs, temporary data and is small
- drive D: holds a Windows image
- drive E: or F: holds your application

On a full deployment, or a re-image, you receive a new virtual machine so all three drives are re-created. On an upgrade, the virtual machine continues to run but the load balancer migrates traffic away while the new version of the application is deployed to drive F:. Drive E: is then removed.

So, answering your question directly, the "template" is for drive E: -- anything else is subject to change without your knowledge, and can't be relied on.

Answer (score 1):

Azure provides Startup Scripts so that you can make configuration changes on instance startup.  Often these are used to install additional OS components or make IIS-configuration changes (like disabling idle timeouts).

See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lucascan/archive/2011/09/30/using-a-windows-azure-startup-script-to-prevent-your-site-from-being-shutdown.aspx for an example.

Comment: O.k. great, Jeremy answered my question and now you'[ve provided the answer to my next question... how to get around a wipe. thx.

Comment: you can't. its the entire principal of their fault tolerance and scalability.  from the devs point of view, you just have resources that are allocated and setup per your deployment package and service configuration.  everything you build for azure should survive this startup and teardown lifecycle.  This is why you use BLOB's for permanent storage instead of local drives.

Answer (score 1):

The existing answers are technically correct and answer the question, but hosting multiple web sites in a single web role doesn't require editing the hosts file at all. Just define multiple  web sites (with different host headers) in your ServiceDefinition.csdef. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg433110.aspx

Comment: Oh Mate that's even better. Thanks alot. I have to stick with the accepted answer however as it's the right answer to my "wrong" question.

Comment: LMAO!!! Holy hell. Are you THAT guy on Cloud Cover???!! If so that's awesome. Wow, talk about straight from the horses mouth. Gotta love the net... and SO. You're, "like", right there. Look it's HIM everybody. It's THAT guy, answering MY question. Brilliant. I'm calling Mum. LOL.

Comment: I'm truely honoured. ;-) Awesome vids too Mr Marx. Fun, informative, focused and quick. Thnx alot.